# Use the button as a toggle to change text and replace one variable with another variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, toggle

I am trying to use the button to change from fahrenheit to celcius and vice versa. I tried to manage to change the text on the button and F/C words next to temperature but the equation `$("#temp").text() === currentTempInCelsius` always return `false`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#changerToC").click(function () {
    var fTemp = currentTempInCelsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
    $("#temp").text() === currentTempInCelsius ? $("#temp").text(fTemp) : $("#temp").text(currentTempInCelsius);
    $("#changerToC").text() ==="Change to Celcius" ? $("#changerToC").text("Change to Fahrenheit") : $("#changerToC").text("Change to Celcius");
    $("#tempunit").text() === "C" ? $("#tempunit").text('F') : $("#tempunit").text('C');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
        <h1 class="title">
            Free C<i class="fa fa-mixcloud"></i>de Camp
            <br>
            Weather App
        </h1>
        <h2 id="city"></h2>
        <h2 id="country"></h2>
        <br><br>        
        <h2 id="temp"></h2>
        <h2 id="tempunit"></h2>
        <br><br>
        <h2 id="desc"></h2>
        <i id="weather-icon" class="fa"></i>
        <br>
        <button id="changerToC" class="btn btn-primary">Change to Fahrenheit</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is it failing?  console errors?

Comment: it is'nt failing. I checked the console log but nothing there. It just didnt change the temperature

Comment: where is `currentTempInCelsius` passed in / retrieved?

Comment: weird, cause your code throws `currentTempInCelsius is undefined` when I run it.

Comment: Sorry I supposed to explain how currentTempInCelsius is retrieved. It is retrived from API dynamically. So after it is received I am trying to change it from fah to celcius or vice versa with button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `===` to `==` like this:

```
     $("#temp").text() == currentTempInCelsius ? $("#temp").text(fTemp) : $("#temp").text(currentTempInCelsius);
```